# how to get name ocean with reverse geocode in android?

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding

I tried to get the name of the ocean or any name you specify me where I am for example "near the coast of Ecuador." Are there a way to get address when a point is in the ocean?

I have dealt with these lines but I get no result.

```
getAdminArea()
getCountryName()
getSubAdminArea()
getFeatureName()
getAddressLine(0)
getCountryCode()
getLocality()
getSubLocality()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not possible with google reverse geocoding but you can use another service like [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html) Reverse Geocoding Webservices.